# node-pre-gyp ERR! every time When running npm-install on macOS Mojave

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, npm-install

I get this annoying error when I run npm-install, tried npm install --build-from-resource and didn't work. And tried installing node-pre-gyp globally. Id did not fix the error too. I have tried several methods but no luck yet.

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/dmcshehan/Desktop/JS/Max test/redux--01-start/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/Users/dmcshehan/Desktop/JS/Max test/redux--01-start/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/dmcshehan/Desktop/JS/Max test/redux--01-start/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/dmcshehan/Desktop/JS/Max test/redux--01-start/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/dmcshehan/Desktop/JS/Max test/redux--01-start/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/dmcshehan/Desktop/JS/Max test/redux--01-start/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.5.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/dmcshehan/Desktop/JS/Max test/redux--01-start/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/dmcshehan/Desktop/JS/Max test/redux--01-start/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.36
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
gyp Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/dmcshehan/Desktop/JS/Max test/redux--01-start/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/dmcshehan/Desktop/JS/Max test/redux--01-start/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64' (1)
ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/dmcshehan/Desktop/JS/Max test/redux--01-start/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/Users/dmcshehan/Desktop/JS/Max test/redux--01-start/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/dmcshehan/Desktop/JS/Max test/redux--01-start/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /Users/dmcshehan/Desktop/JS/Max test/redux--01-start/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

added 1133 packages from 734 contributors and audited 11147 packages in 46.08s
found 699 vulnerabilities (350 low, 317 moderate, 31 high, 1 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: Do you have xcode installed? `xcodebuild -version`

Comment: yes i have it installed, but it gives me this error : error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance